# Successive amplitudes in quantum mechanics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, newtonian-mechanics

In quantum mechanics we define amplitudes for events, like propagation from one point to some other point. Lets say that from a source to detector we have some amplitude (D/S).
But, lets now say that we have one mid point. Now we can say that the amplitude from S to M (midpoint) and then to D is (D/M)(M/S). Why multiply?

Comment: What would you do instead? Add? Why add?

Comment: Didnt say that. But i was just wondering.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because amplitudes are related to probabilities, and that's how the laws of probability work.

A fair die has a probability of $1/6$ of landing on any side. If you roll the die twice, the probability of rolling a 6 the first time **and** rolling a 6 the second time is $1/6\times 1/6=1/36$. Likewise, for a single roll, the probability of rolling a 5 **or** rolling a 6 is $1/6+1/6=1/3$. So you see that the laws of probability dictate the following:

> The probability of one event happening **and** another mutually-exclusive event happening is the **product** of the probabilities of the two events happening.
>
> The probability of one event happening **or** another mutually-exclusive event happening is the **sum** of the probabilities of the two events happening.

So the probability of the particle traveling from S to M to D is the probability of traveling from S to M **and** traveling from M to D, hence is equal to the **product** of the two individual probabilities. Since the squared magnitude of the amplitude is the probability, it should be straightforward to see that amplitudes should follow the same rule, since $|a||b|=|ab|$.

Comment: Tnx man. I thought so my self but wasnt sure.

Comment: Also, to add, I see this law for successive probabilities as consequence of the fact that in two dice rolls you have total of 36 permutations , 6 times 6. So, if you define probability as number of desireable events over the number of total events you get for example 1 over 36. Now what I was worried was the generalization of this to events like those in QM where we do not have a discrete situation. I guess generalization is ok. But also would be nice to see the proof. In QM book also. Just to be sure.